# When I try to use linux expect to ssh remote machine, the authentication is very slow ,why?

Tags: linux, expect

I try to use it , but I find It is very slow .

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set hostname [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh "xxx\@$hostname"
expect "password: "
send "xxxxx\r"
expect "$ "
send "sudo su admin\r"
expect "assword:\n"
send "xxxxx\r"
expect "$ "
send "cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub >> /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys\r"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Which statement is very slow? what does `ssh -v` show when connecting? - where is it hanging? what does the ssh log show?

Comment: Usually, when working with expect, "very slow" means things are not working as you would want them to, since you're having expect statements time out.

Answer (score 1):

Add `exp_internal 1` to the top of your script so you can watch what expect is doing.

I suspect this is wrong: `expect "assword:\n"` -- I bet the actual password prompt does not end with a newline. Try removing `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Try

ssh -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no login@remoteipipaddress

if successful.. need to edit /etc/ssh/ssh_config and  /etc/ssh/sshd_config
and looking for GSSAPIAuthentication. Please change value to "no".

it's working for me.